# Create Drop-down List By Reading Data From Properties File in Grails

Tags: java, grails, groovy, properties, gsp

How to generate drop-down list by reading data from message.properties file using Grails? I already created the domain file:

```
  class Feedback {

    enum Type {
    COMPT("compt") ,
    COMPL("compl") ,
    ENQ("enq")

    final String typeID 
    Type (String typeID){
        this.typeID = typeID
    }
    String toString(){
        typeID
    } 
}



    static constraints = {
        typeID inList: Type.values()*.typeID
       }
}
```

Here is my data stored in message.properties file

```
  type.compt=Complaint
  type.compl=Compliment
  type.enq=Enquiry
```

How to display the information in GSP using taglib?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the message based on the given parameter, you could use

```
<g:message code="type.${passedFeedbackType}" />
```

Generating a dropdown list from a enum list is basically done as following:

```
<g:select name="yourList" value="${value_you_want_to_have_first}" 
          from="${Feedback.Type.values()}" optionValue="${it}" 
optionKey="typeId"/>
```

But you want to have the property message as a value. You can also use `message` from the taglib as

```
${g.message(code:'your.message.code')}
```

So the solution to your problem would be, for example

```
<select>
    <g:each in="${Feedback.Type.values()}" var="feedbackType">
        <option value="${type}">${g.message(code:"type.${type}")}</option>
    </g:each>
</select>
```

Because somehow I can't get it working with `<g:select>`, but eventually it also generates pure HTML.
Just remember to have all the corresponding messages in the properties.

Comment: @KCKoay Glad that helped! If it solved your problem, you can now mark this answer as accepted (and upvote it if you like). 
Thanks!

Comment: Sorry I cannot upvote as my reputation is less than 1 but I mark this answer as accepted. Thanks again for helping!